# For offline application, Using Squish,How to check, whether a lin is broken or not?

Tags: qt, squish

Using Squish Automation Tool.

I have Windows QT application, It contains links for
1. Files
2. Folder
3. Other Apllication.

Is there any function or way to check whether these links are broken or not?

I don't want to click each any every link. What I need is that, I get a object of parent Window, and by using some function it should check whether all links present are active or broken.
I know there is a function in QTP, but don't have any idea for SQUISH.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What type of control (i.e. what's the value of the `type` property) does Squish show for the link control?

Comment: the value for type is 65536.

Comment: Are you sure `65536` is the name of the `type` property? It doesn't sound like a typical value for `type`, usually it's something like `WindowsControl` or `Button` or so. Did you maybe take the value of the `class` property?

Comment: Yes, I have Launch the AUT, then pick that object. After that checked the properties of that object, in type it is showing the same.